# What's the correct way to implement login page in Xamarin Shell?

Tags: xamarin.forms

My app has structure like this.

Splash page => Login page => Main page

After login, user cannot go back to login/splash page. There are several pages in flyout menu that user can go to. However, login/splash items should not be showed in these flyout menu items.

Some project may try to load main page first before show login page as a modal page. I think this way doesn't work because it should take so much time to load complex main page before send user back to login.

Comment: LoginPage should be inside the Shell, see my post ;)

Answer (score 42):

Main goal of having logins screen is to only show when user is not logged to app. 
Answers cover only parts of solution. Here is how i archived my login solution.
My goal: when app starts, then check if user is logged. If so then goto MainPage, else go to LoginPage. Same principle could be used to show app first run screens.

Download [ShellLoginSample](https://github.com/davidortinau/ShellLoginSample) 
Replace order of items in AppShell.xaml

```
<!--  Your Pages  -->
<TabBar Route="main">
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>

<ShellItem Route="login">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</ShellItem>
```

Then edit App.xaml.cs to check login state

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
    var isLoogged = Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.GetAsync("isLogged").Result;
    if (isLoogged == "1")
    {
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }
}
```

Then edit in LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
protected async void OnClicked(object source, EventArgs args)
{
    await Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.SetAsync("isLogged", "1");
    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Just a question. What is the need for "await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main");"? I justed deleted this line and everything worked fine.

Comment: Probably just copied from sample from Github. I just leave it as technically you could go to any other page not only main.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer, by doing this, every time you go to main page (AppShell) it will load Login page unexpectedly.

Comment: Thats what is point of login page. Not allow user see other pages.  Could you link to correct implementation?

Comment: Could you give suggestions how to fix?

Comment: LoginPage should be inside the Shell.  it's blinking when changing MainPage like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylbgWHB_gMI

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand. What do you mean "LoginPage should be inside the Shell" what do you mean shell? Video is 15min long i am not sure which part i should look into? Maybe you could provide correct implementations in answers bellow?

Comment: Ok I made an answer on this thread, just check it out ;)

Answer (score 13):

The best way is to make your LoginPage the landing Page with this code

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

then after successful login, you then Navigate to ShellApp using the following code

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
```

Then you can use `Xam.SettingsPlugin` to store your token and userId.
To log out simple navigate away from the AppShell by using the following code..

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

there is a enhanceent request from Xamarin forms github repo requesting inbuilt login page, here is the link [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5272)

Comment: In my experience this doesn't work. The LoginPage isn't rendered correctly when navigating back to the LoginPage. The answer of @valentasm works thou
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348505/3506115

Comment: This is nice and the LoginPage rendered correctly when navigating back. The only downside is it forces the user to log in every time app starts, which is a pain in the booty during development.

Comment: LoginPage should be inside the Shell. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylbgWHB_gMI

Answer (score 5):

Xamrin.Forms Vesion:4.6 have made the Login flow very easy. This is the link to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout). The developer have the flexibility to choose the `CurrentItem` of the Shell irrespective of the order of the items defined in the `AppShell.xaml` file. This can be done in `AppShell.xaml` as well as `AppShell.xaml.cs`

Check Login state in App.xaml.cs and send parameter to AppShell file accordingly

```
    public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (isLogged)
    {
        MainPage = new AppShell("mainpage");
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new AppShell("loginpage");
    }
}
```

In AppShell.Xaml define your app structure.

```
<ShellItem>
        <ShellContent x:Name="loginpage"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}"
                      Route="loginpage" />
    </ShellItem>

    <TabBar x:Name="mainpage" Route="mainpage">
        <ShellContent Title="Dashboard" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Finance" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FinancePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Profile" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProfilePage}" />
    </TabBar>
```

In the AppShell.xaml.cs select the CurrentItem as per the parameter received from App.xaml.cs.

```
public AppShell(string currentItem)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Shell shell = new Shell();

            switch (currentItem)
            {
                case "login":

                    shell.CurrentItem = loginpage;
                    break;

                case "mainpage":
                    shell.CurrentItem = mainpage;
                    break;

            }

        }
```

The `CurrentItem` is selected on referring the `x:Name` Property of the `ShellItem`.
The `CurrentItem` property can be set in any class through the Shell.Current static property:

Shell.Current.CurrentItem = loginpage;

Comment: `AppShell` constructor does not accept any parameter, where did you get this sample?

Comment: Please see the complete sample.It accepts if you send the parameter from App.Xaml.cs. Are you sending the parameter from App.Xaml.cs?

Comment: James Montemagno explaining here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylbgWHB_gMI

Answer (score 2):

You should create like this. In App.xaml.cs call the your first ContentPage (Login Page)

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()); // LoginPage is contentPage
    }
```

From LoginPage you can validate the fields and synch with api. Based on the response(success/failure) you can redirect to MainPage(Home Page)

```
if (loginStatus == "isSuccess") {
    // if it ie MasterController/Drawer view/flyout menu/menu view
    Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterControllerPage(); // need to create a page in the type 'MasterDetailPage' 

           //or normal content page use this(here HomePage is your MainPage) 
   Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
}
else
{
    // handle error alert
   DisplayAlert("Sorry", "Something went wrong in server.", "Ok");
}
```

For Splash page in Android look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

For Splash page in iOS look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos

Comment: I already tried this way. But it's quite laggy when I change main page of application to Xamarin Shell container. Can I have page transition for this action?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell?tabs=android

Comment: @Soul_Master you need custom side drawer or menu view right? As my point of view using MasterDetailPage is easy for that also we easily customize as

Comment: Flyout menu is a part of Xamarin Shell that will be availabled in Xamarin Form 4.0. Currently, I use Xamarin Form 4.0 preview 4 for this project.

Comment: Did you check this?  https://github.com/sarahonorato/Flyout-Menu-with-Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I knew about this kind of flyout menu control. But I think Xamarin Shell provide much more flexible solution to solve all navigation problems in Xamarin Form.

Answer (score 2):

I want to create two AppShell. One will be the principal, with all my menu for my application. The other one only will have a login page.

So you can switch between one AppShel and the other.

```
MainPage = new AppShell();

MainPage = new LoginAppShell();
```

Comment: This worked for me. Is there any downside? Can I have more AppShells?

Answer (score 1):

### The correct way is to only set the MainPage one time like so, to prevent blink.

###### App.xaml.cs

```cs
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        if (await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("_token"))
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//Dashboard");
        else
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//SignIn");
    }
```

###### AppShell.xaml

###### should have a route to a SplashScreen and a SignInPage,In this order.

```xml
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"> 
       <!-- Locked/Flyout -->
    
    <ShellItem x:Name="_splashScreen" Route="SplashScreen" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SplashScreen}" />
    </ShellItem>
    <!-- SplahshScreen is here because SecureStorage is asynchronous and we need 
         to show something during this time of process. -->
    
    <ShellItem x:Name="_signInPage" Route="SignIn" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SignInPage}"/>
    </ShellItem>

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Route="Dashboard"
                      Title="Dashboard"
                      Icon="menu_dashboard.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Dashboard}" />
        <ShellContent Route="Others"
                      Title="Others"
                      Icon="menu_others.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:OthersPage}" />
        ...
    </FlyoutItem>
...
```

###### SignInPage.xaml and splashScreen.xaml

###### should never show the FlyoutMenu or the Tabbar

```xml
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
```

###### And here we go when logged, the FlyoutMenu slide gently on the interface, no blink :)

Answer (score 0):

In your App.xaml.cs add the following line:

```
 public App()
 {
 InitializeComponent();
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
 }
```

Than in your authentication file add:

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            PhoneNumber = PhoneNumberEntry.Text,
            Password = PasswordEntry.Text
        };
        if (user.PhoneNumber == Dummy.PhoneNumber && user.Password == Dummy.Password)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
        else
        {
            messagelabel.Text = "Invalid Login";
            PasswordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

This worked for me.. hope it helps you guys too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this way,

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private AppShell _mainMenu;
    private LoginPage _loginPage;
    public static App Instance;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set singleton
        Instance = this;
        // Check here for previus-login user
        if (SystemEnvironment.UserCurrentSession != null)
        {
            SwitchToMainMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            SwitchToLogin();
        }
    }

    public void SwitchToLogin()
    {
        _loginPage = null;
        _loginPage = new LoginPage();
        MainPage = _loginPage; // Go to login page
    }

    public void SwitchToMainMenu()
    {
        _mainMenu = null;
        _mainMenu = new AppShell();
        MainPage = _mainMenu; // Go to logged user page
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: have you try logout? replace the shell with the login page.

Comment: When I try to logout, calling back the SwitchToLogin method, it doesn't work, and the app stay in the appshell. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: have a viewmodel for the xaml

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand LogoutCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            LogoutCommand = new Command(() => Logout() );
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            // Logout the user
            SystemEnvironment.UserCurrentSession = null;
            App.Instance.SwitchToLogin();
        }
    }

and in the appshell.xaml

 <MenuItem Text="Cerrar sesión" Icon="closesession.png" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" />

Answer (score 0):

> To **hide** the *splash, register, login* etc. pages from the `AppShell`
>   Flyout menu, you can use a **custom** `FlyoutItem` `DataTemplateSelector`
>   that returns a view with no height for the corresponding ShellContent
>   page.

This [Medium](https://medium.com/@thebaileybrew/xamarin-forms-shell-lets-customize-the-flyout-menu-de3df2450f56) article by @Matthew Bailey explains really well how to implement it.

For the pages you don't want to show as a menu options, create a `DataTemplate` that returns a view with no height.

Hidden `ShellItem` `DataTemplate` example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlyoutHiddenItemTemplate">
                <BoxView HeightRequest="0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
```

And return it in the `DataTemplateSelector` `OnSelectTemplate` method

```
   protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            if(item is BaseShellItem flyoutItem)
            { 
    //Example: If the item has no title? we do not want to show it.
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(flyoutItem.Title))
                    return FlyoutHiddenItemTemplate;
            } 
            return NavigationItemTemplate;
        }
```

This [AppShell login flow sample](https://github.com/davidortinau/ShellLoginSample) by @davidortinau is a good starting point to implement this solution.