# calling GoToAsync in OnNavigatedTo throws exception "pending navigations still processing"

Tags: maui

Using GoToAsync with a route starting with "///" throws exception "pending navigations still processing"; where-as using a route without the "///" prefix sort of works.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs e)
{
  var result = await IsAuthenticated();
  if (result)
  {
      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///HomePage"); // exception here, route in appshell.xaml
      // await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("HomePage"); // no exception, route in appshell.xaml.ca
  }
  else
  {
      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoginPage)); // works
  }
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

The problem with not using the "///" is the Home Page is floating outside of the AppShell context, so the tabs and flyouts defined in AppShell.xaml are not shown.

Question: why does GoToAsync("HomePage") work while GoToAsync("\\HomePage") fail?

Obviously has to do with the navigation stack; so I am missing something with how that works.

Option 1: move the code outside of the OnNavigatedTo event, but will that run into similar issue
Option 2: use alternative navigation (push/pop?)

using MAUI 7.0.92; testing on windows.

I have looked at
[Login page for .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269299/login-page-for-net-maui/74291417#74291417)

UPDATE 1:
found something else [What's the correct way to implement login page in Xamarin Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586621/whats-the-correct-way-to-implement-login-page-in-xamarin-shell)

This article doesn't answer my question as to why one gotoasync URI works and the other doesnt.

This article does resolve my navigation need; by using the App.OnStart event instead of a OnNavigatedTo event... this fixes the problem by moving the code elsewhere.

UPDATE 2: in response to ToolmakerSteve

1. default first page in appshell.xaml is "loadingPage".
2. yes, LoadingPage.xaml.cs has the OnNavigatedTo event.
3. yes, HomePage is referenced in appshell.xaml in a shellcontent tag as follows

```
    <TabBar>
      <Tab Title="Home" >
         <ShellContent
             Title="Home"
             ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"
             Route="HomePage" />        
     </Tab>
...
```

4. I have tried including and excluding the RegisterRoute("HomePage","HomePage"); If the route is NOT registered the exception thrown is "relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported".
5. I have tried both GoToAsync("///HomePage"); and GoToAsync("//HomePage"); and every other variation i could think of. the call GoToAsync("//HomePage") throws the "pending navigations still processing"
6. Using the Dispatcher does work! Yeah. Thx.

While this approach can "work", I feel that what I am trying to do is throwing an exception, because I am not following the "correct" navigation flow for app shell.

UPDATE 3: RTFM

For routing in GoToAsync(aRoute); there are 5 options

1. absolute URI: //animal/domestic/cat
2. relative URI: aRoute = "cat"; search route hierarchy upwards from current location, matching page is pushed on navigation stack
3. relative URI: aRoute = "/cat"; search route hierarchy DOWNWARDS from current location, matching page is pushed on navigation stack
4. relative URI: aRoute = "//cat"; search route hierarchy upwards from current location, matching page REPLACES navigation stack
5. relative URI: aRoute = "///cat"; search route hierarchy DOWNWARDS from current location, matching page REPLACES navigation stack

Helps explain why different exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: have you tried putting your code *after* the `base` call?

Comment: yes. no difference.

Comment: Add an "UPDATE" section at end of question, to show more context. 1) What is the default (first page) of AppShell? For what you are doing to make sense, it must NOT be "HomePage". 2) Is `OnNavigatedTo` on that first page? 3) Is "HomePage" referenced in a `ShellContent` inside `<Shell>` XAML? 4) Is there a `Routing.RegisterRoute("HomePage")`? IMPORTANT: If BOTH (3) and (4) are true, REMOVE the `RegisterRoute` line. 5) Try `GoToAsync("//HomePage")`. 6) If nothing else fixes, try `Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//HomePage"))};`. [Add answers to question.]