# Tabs in not appearing in MainPage .net maui

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Here's my AppShell.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="DemoApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoApp"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage"/>

    <TabBar Route="MainPage">
        <Tab Title="Dashboard">
            <ShellContent Icon="DashboardTabIcon.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:tab1}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="SecondTab">
            <ShellContent Icon="SecondTabIcon.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:tab1}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I am expecting that bottom tabbar should appear on my MainPage but it is not happening. What should i do ? Any .Net Maui Developer here. Kindly guide me.

Comment: `MainPage` needs to be inside of the `TabBar`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs follow this strictly.

Comment: It's working jason but When i navigate MainPage to HomePage (HomePage tabs not appearing). although when i use tabs in MainPage its appearing. I want to use tabs in homepage or after mainPage. I am new to .net maui. any guidance will help me alot.

Comment: Why do you have “Route=MainPage” in two different places? Fix this. Then try again. If still doesn’t work, update question with revised code, and the details of what is happening (copy what you say in your comment above into the question if that is still the symptom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but When i navigate MainPage to HomePage (HomePage tabs not appearing)

I created a demo and achieved this function, you can refer to the following code.

1.Define your pages in `AppShell.xaml` and add Route for your pages(for example, add `Route="home"` for the `TabBar`), just as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp820.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp820"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiApp820.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellItem Route="main">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </ShellItem>

    <TabBar  Title="home"
             Route="home"
            >

        <Tab Title="Dashboard" Icon="cat.png">
            <ShellContent 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:TabPage1}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="SecondTab" Icon="dog.png">
            <ShellContent 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:TabPage2}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

2.add a Button on page `MainPage` and add a click event, if we click the button, then it will navigate to the `HomePage` tabs.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {  
          // naviagte to Home Tabbar
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//home");

      }
}
```

3.`App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();

      }
}
```

Note:

This is similar to the often discussed Login problem in the shell, you can refer to thread: [whats-the-correct-way-to-implement-login-page-in-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348505/10308336). Although this is based on Xamarin, the same applies to MAUI.